# Использование таймера для автоматического сохранения в файл графической сцены в Qt проекте

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Каким образом можно реализовать таймер, который после запуска программы каждые 5 секунд сохраняет текущую графическую сцену в файл svgnext.svg ? Это происходит во время работы программы, до тех пор пока не будет закрыто окно графической сцены.

На данный момент графическая сцена сохраняется в файл только при запуске программы.

Моя реализация таймера:

```
timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::saveTimer);
timer->start(5000);
```

Метод сохранения в файл:

```
void MainWindow::saveTimer()
{
    QSvgGenerator generator;        
    generator.setFileName("svgnext.svg");    
    generator.setSize(QSize(scene->width(), scene->height()));  
    generator.setViewBox(QRect(0, 0, scene->width(), scene->height())); 

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&generator); 
    scene->render(&painter);    
    painter.end();             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно добавить в конце `saveTimer()` строку `timer->start(std::chrono::seconds{5});`.

Или же при подписке на сигнал можно сделать так:

```
timer = new QTimer(this); // Таймер должен удалиться вместе с родительским объектом, иначе будут проблемы
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this, timer]{
   saveTimer();
   timer->start(std::chrono::seconds{5})
});

timer->start(std::chrono::seconds{5});
```

EDIT: или можно установить флаг, разрешающий повтор: `timer->setSingleShot(false);`